# SPD 2010 task list

Tags: sharepoint, xpath

I am trying to write a workflow using SPD 2010 that is triggered upon item creation in a document library.

I want to set up a task that is mailed to the user in a task-mail with a subject like  - **Tasks -  ... has been assigned to you**
(which is the default task-mail that you get in case of collect data from user form).

Is there a way to *present the user with values of fields of the Current Item* (the creation of which triggered the workflow) in the task form, the button to which task form is provided in the task-mail?

Comment: By default, there is an xsn form created for this type of tasks. I tried modifying that in InfoPath. I added a dropdownlist that takes its choices from external data source which is my list. Don't know the XPATH expression that will take the most recent item from my list.

Comment: tried something like this, doesnt work :S -  /dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW[d:ID = xdMath:Max(d:ID)]

Comment: I was able to do what I was trying to using the "Collect Feedback from User" form .  Using Collect feedback form I was able to lookup list field values and add those lookups to the default emails that come with that form.----Not an answer but some workaround. [^_^]

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the workflow start will first create the task for users in task list.Get the task ID and task list ID that was created for this workflow instance, and construct an URL like - http://SITE_URL/_layouts/WrkTaskIP.aspx?List=LIST_ID&ID=TASK_ID&Source=http://redirect_url_once_task_completed.aspx  where WrkTaskIP.aspx is the task edit form.Send this as a href link for text in the mail body.
It would be better if you have a data entity class to store information about your object(the item field values).You can use this in your email for information.